# Aggregate by column with empty values in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I've been struggling with this one for a while. I need to remove "duplicates" in my dataframe composed like this:

```
---------------------
X     |  Y   |  Z   |
---------------------
team1 | ABC  | DEF  |
team1 |      |      |
team2 |      |      |
team2 | GHK  | LMN  |
team3 |      | RST  |
team4 | UVW  | WYZ  |
```

I need the outcome to be:

```
team1 | ABC  | DEF  |
team2 | GHK  | LMN  |
team3 |      | RST  |
team4 | UVW  | WYZ  |
```

The problem is, not all rows have these empty values. I've tried using fist('Y', True), i've tried first(coalesce(col('Y')), True) but these are not nulls, just empty values. As result i removed duplicates, but as values i got empty values. Is there a way to pick a first non-empty value if it exist? 
Some rows are have "naturally" empty values, no duplicates there. Sorry, I'm new here, thank you so much!

Comment: What if one of the duplicate X has Y value only and the other has Z value only? Which one do you want to choose in that case?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  In my case that is not possible due to the nature of my dataset. It is either all values or no values (empty values). If values were integers i would simply use max, but I can't since it's a string. I may consider re-organizing the whole join setup (my data arrive from 6 different datasets) and deal with these values beforehand, trying to ignore them completely...